# Typescript namespaces in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, namespaces

- src/model/generated/MyCLabs/Enum/Enum.ts

```
export namespace MyCLabs {
export namespace Enum {
export namespace Enum {


export class Enum {

    
        value : null;
        
        key : null;
        
        cache : null;
        
        instances : null;
        
    constructor(obj : Enum) {
        
        
        

        Object.assign(this,obj);
        
    }
}
}
}
}
```

- /test.ts

```
import MyCLabs from "src/model/generated/MyCLabs/Enum/Enum";

let test : MyCLabs.Enum.Enum.Enum = new MyCLabs.Enum.Enum.Enum();
```

- tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/js/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I am trying to utilize TS's namespace in webpack 5, however webpack has the following error:

> TS2307 cannot find module "path/to/ts" or corresponding type declaration:1 test.ts

when trying to import the said ts file. Am I right to say webpack doesn't support TS namespaces? If so how best can I emulate the namespace strategy as I am working on a project with dozens of classes with identical names

Comment: namespaces work fine with webpack. Can you share an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: You only need to import the top level `namespace`, did you try that ?

Comment: yes tried. my IDE(phpstorm) is able to navigate to the class. unfortunately TSC and webpack compile still throws module not found error at line 1 for test.ts

Answer (score 0):

just having rootDir in tsconfig was not enough:

needed the 2 options(baseUrl/include) that correctly resolved the source dir

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/js/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```